# Delphi XE3 Fatal Compilation Error in jlcSysInfo

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, jedi-code-library

New to XE3, when I try to compile a small application with a JVCL component on it
I get the following error:

```
[dcc32 Fatal Error] JclSysInfo.pas(1402): F2051 Unit JclRegistry was compiled
with a different version of JclBase.HexFmt
```

can anyone offer a resolution ?

Comment: ouch, I think you need to recompile everything in a specific order, maybe using the Jedi installer is the way to go?

Comment: You have multiple copies of Jcl compiled (dcu) files in your library or search paths, or of JclBase, etc.  This is a duplicate.